# MATLAB GUI issue with getting/setting values

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I'm facing a problem in MATLAB that I don't really know what might be the cause. I have a GUI build with GUIDE on MATLAB R2007b. In this GUI I have a edit used for typing in a file name that is then used for saving some data. I use the edit callback function to test if the file name is valid by checking the string received with `get(hObject,'String')` on emptyness and then activate/ deactivate the load button if the typed file name exists or not. The string value gets also saved into a variable in the handles structure.

The issue I'm facing now is, that for some reason, the setting of the file name does not work if i type the name 'default' or if the name typed is empty. The statement in the `if (isempty(handles.fileName))` block gets executed when nothing is typed in the edit. when default is typed in the string shown in the edit is deleted. Below you can find the code of the callback function.

In the OpeningFcn:

```
    handles.fileName = 'default';
```

My Callback:

```
    function edit_fileName_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
        handles.fileName = get(hObject,'String');
        if (isempty(handles.fileName))
            handles.fileName = 'default';
            disp(handles.fileName)
        end
        handles.fileName = strrep(handles.fileName,' ','_');
        set(hObject,'String',handles.fileName);

        if exist(['trajectories/' handles.fileName '.mat'],'file') == 2
            set(handles.pushbutton_load,'Enable','on')  
        else
            set(handles.pushbutton_load,'Enable','off')
        end

        guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Has someone an idea why this issue might occur? I'm hanging now for quite some time on this issue and have not found yet any solution.

Thanks

Edit 1:

what i found out so far is that the value returned from get(hObject,'String'); and the string coded `handles.fileName = 'default'`; are not exactly the same. I've added the line `disp(['fileName: ' handles.fileName])` to the callback and it shows the a difference with a typed name or when set in the code:

Self typed:

```
    fileName:  test
```

Set by code:

```
    fileName:  
    default
```

The coded version somehow adds itself a newline.

Edit 2:

The issue described in Edit 1 was due to a misplacement of the `disp` command.

**Edit 3 / Workaround:**
It seems that the string `'default'` itself was the cause of trouble. When using another default value it works seamlessly. Furthermore, when `'default'` is typed in the field the edit itself does not work properly anymore. seems to be some bug.

Comment: Is the call back connected to any keys being typed or only when the return key is pressed?  It could be this call back is being executed more offten than you think, try to dump `handles.fileName` on every call to debug it.

Comment: the callback is called after some text has been typed into the edit and the edit itself gets defocused (by clicking on some other edit, pressing tab/enter...) i've tried already to dump someting in the callback to the command window but the callback gets really only called when expected

Comment: You code looks okay to me.  Is there any other callback tied to the edit?  Could another callback be editing the string property?

Comment: No, no other callback is tied to the edit. what i found out so far is that the value returned from `get(hObject,'String');` and the string coded `handles.fileName = 'default';` are not exactly the same.  I've added the line `disp(['fileName:  ' handles.fileName])` to the callback and it shows the a difference with a typed name or when set by pc (see original post edit)

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that this came from another source. i placed the `disp` at the wrong position in the code

Comment: I was about to suggest that, you could try using `fprintf('fileName = "%s"\n', handles.fileName)` so that the string is in quotes.  And place it outside the if block to see every callback execution

Comment: I tried your suggestion. The results are both times the same. I also looked if the types are the same with `whos`

Comment: Next, try placing `fprintf` at the beginning of the callback, and at the end, so we should see if somehow it get's changed.  Place a `fprintf` anywhere `handles.fileName` is referred to.  Place a label for each so you know which one is being called like `fprintf('1: filename = "%s"\n', handles.fileName);`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The results are exactly as they should be. if I type some random name it shows at each step `fileName = "test"` , if the name is empty the first output is `""` and from the second on it gets changed to `"default"` and if the typed name is `"default"` it shows `fileName = "default"` from beginning.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you type `default` in the edit, after the callback, it shows up as ``.  Try adding some constant text to see if that shows up, try adding this line at the top `handles.fileName = [handles.fileName '_hello'];`, to confirm that `_hello` always shows up.

Comment: Finally... It works :D. or at least a workaround, When using `handles.fileName = [handles.fileName '_hello'];` or another word instead of `'_hello'` the complete string shows up in the field and also in the handle. Intrestingly, the Problem shows up again if i use `[handles.fileName 't'];` and type `'defaul'` in the field. It seems that (this particular version of) Matlab does not like the word `'default'`

Comment: Wow!  One last thing to check though, it's possible there is an anonymous function for a callback that you won't see in the .m file GUIDE writes out, please review the properties in GUIDE that there isn't some other callback or input verifier callback messing you up.  I've had an anonymous callback problem before and took forever to discover it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Nick. I looked if there is some other callback in the GUIDE properties but I could not find anything. The issue seems to be in matlab itself. With every other word as default value it works...

Comment: Cheers!  Got to love that buggy MATLAB!